# p:rowToggler not working in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to make a row expand but it is resulting in Java error.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.primefaces.component.rowtoggler.RowTogglerRenderer.encodeEnd(RowTogglerRenderer.java:32
```

My XHTML code is

```
<p:panelGrid rendered="#{SearchController.response}">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width:16px">
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="Year :" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{SearchController.year}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width:16px">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="Total No. Of GS:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{SearchController.empCount}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I did check on the PrimeFaces blogs to find the issue but was unable to find anything.

Any help will be of great help.

Regards.

Comment: I think rowTogler can be used only with data table ? Check example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml

Comment: I already checked that. Was trying to build using the same concept. Here also the panelgrid is inside the datatable.